# Получить связи m2m в обратном порядке

Tags: python, база-данных, django, many-to-many

Есть две модели, со связью многие ко многим

```
class ProductCategory(MPTTModel):
    """Категории"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True,)
    #parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']            
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):    
    """Продукты"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)     
    category_id = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory, related_name="category_product") 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Мне нужно исходя из категории получить  все продукты

```
queryset = Product.objects.prefetch_related('category_id')
stores = []
for store in queryset:
    category = [book.name for book in store.category_id.all()]
    stores.append({'id': store.id, 'name': store.name, 'category': category})
print(stores)
```

А получается наоборот, получаю все категории продукта:

```
[{'id': 8, 'name': 'Продукт1', 'category': ['Вкладыши шатунные', 'ГБЦ', 'Буферы']}]
```

Как из категории получить  все продукты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить в `ProductCategory` метод `get_products` который вернёт все продукты связанные с конкретной категорией:

```
class ProductCategory(MPTTModel):
    """Категории"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True,)
    #parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']            
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_products(self):
        return self.category_product.all()
```

Ну и по вашему примеру:

```
categories = ProductCategory.objects.prefetch_related('category_product')
stores = []
for category in categories:
    products = [{'product_id: product.id', 'product_name': product.name} for product in category.get_products()]
    stores.append({'category_id': category.id, 'category_name': category.name, 'products': products})
```

Comment: не много не понимаю откуда взялось в методе get_products это category_product

Comment: @АндрейИванов а где вы видите метод `category_product `?

Comment: category_product.all() TypeError: get_products() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @АндрейИванов я же написал что метод `get_products` нужно добавить в вашу модель `ProductCategory`

Comment: Добавил в модель, конечно. У меня ругается на это "category_product.all()"

Comment: а `self` добавлять пробовали? как в моем примере

Comment: Да, конечно.  return self.category_product.all()

Comment: Всё, понял))) я в какой-то момент связь переимновал в category_productS

Comment: всё ещё происходит TypeError: get_products() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111758/discussion-between-5c0rp-and--).